# how to return elasticsearch "took" information on GET request?

Tags: elasticsearch

When using the search api elasticsearch returns "took" as part of the response, which gives some insight into the query execution time, however I don't get that using the GET API when fetching a document.

Is there a way to get some timing information from elasticsearch for GET queries?

example query:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/example/_doc/123
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response body defined in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#docs-get-api-response-body) it doesn't look like it. Retrieving a single document is instantaneous as far as ES is concerned because it knows exactly where to look for the document. No need to do the scatter gather approach across multiple shards which takes time - hence the "took" field in the response.